# Installing an Application without Admin Privileges in Win 10

Tags: excel, plugins, windows-10, vsto, non-admin

I have developed a **VSTO** project for **MS excel**. I need to create setup file that runs without admin privileges in **Window 10**. Any method to achieve this?

Comment: In my experience clickonce deployments don't need admin privileges. I guess in your case it depends on what other install activities are required. As long as these are local to the user, you should be fine i guess. What gave you find yourself, eg. using Google?

Comment: Yeah! I am implementing this for my organization. In there I can not use ClickOnce. I found an alternative of using WiX for this purpose and it succeeded. Thank you in advance!